# Nvidia eGPU compatibility with a 2015 MacBookPro running a DualBoot (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: gpu, dual-boot, compatibility

My question is very specific, but I hope someone has already encounter a similar problem.

I want to use a Nvidia eGPU, GeForce RTX™ 2080 Ti with my early 2015 MacBook pro (Thunderbolt 2 only).

I will only use that GPU on Ubuntu 16.04 from a dualboot.

The eGPU is declared as thunderbolt compatible by nvidia : https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4565/~/support-list-for-external-gpus-using-thunderbolt-3-in-windows

I was thinking of plugging it in that way :

- Running Ubuntu Dualboot -> Thunderbolt 2 cabe male-male -> Thunderbolt 3 (USB-c) to Thunderbolt 2 apple connector -> plug it into USB-c port of the eGPU.

I heard that this Thunderbolt 3 to thunderbolt 2 connector works only if the device is thunderbolt compatible, which seems to be the case ? For sure the performance will be slowed down by the Thunderbolt 2 interface, but that's not a problem.

Has anyone ever experienced a similar setup ? Do you think it will be compatible ?
Or do you guys know any other way of using this eGPU through a thunderbolt 2 ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Do you have a problem? Or are just asking if this is a compatible setup before you buy it?

Comment: Just asking before buying the adaptor and cable (so it's not a big deal, I already have the eGPU for other uses).

Comment: Did this work out for you?